# Any Variable Name in Kotlin

Tags: java, typescript, variables, generics, kotlin

I have a typescript class and it accepts any as member name:

```
interface ControlTagType {
    type?: String | null;

    [name: string]: any
}

class ControlTag {
    tagSource: String | null = null;

    tag: ControlTagType | null = null;
}

export { ControlTag };
```

in this way I can use this class in vuejs as following:

```
controlTag.push({ tagSource: 'USER', tag: { type: 'X', TAG_1: 'TAG_X' } });
controlTag.push({ tagSource: 'AUTO', tag: { type: 'Y', TAG_2: 'TAG_Y' } });
```

This is only solution for my another problem.

But I couldn't find how to achieve this generic member in kotlin:

I have an enum class and I used this while serializing:

```
  @JsonValue
  fun value(): X {
    return X( this.name : this.name)
  }
```

such as

```
data class X(val [name: string]: any)
```

I can do as following but it is too complicated and should be done for each class:

```
 @JsonValue
  fun value(): Any? {
    when (this.name) {
      XX_XX.name -> {
        return object {
          var XX_XX: String = name
        }
      }
      YY_YY.name -> {
        return object {
          var YY_YY: String = name
        }
      }
      ZZ_ZZ.name -> {
        return object {
          var ZZ_ZZ: String = name
        }
      }
      else -> return null
    }
  }
```

Also in this implementation it convert parameter name to lower case:

```
{"type":"XX","xx_XX":"XX_XX"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are no index types in Kotlin.**

But you may use different implementations based on interface instead of `val[name: string]: any`

```
interface ControlTagType {
  val type: String?
}

data class ControlTag(
    val tagSource: String? = null,
    val tag: ControlTagType? = null
)

data class FirstControlTagType(
    override val type: String? = null,
    val firstOne: String? = null
) : ControlTagType

data class SecondControlTagType(
    override val type: String? = null,
    val secondOne: String? = null
) : ControlTagType
```

Kotlin designed for multiple languages and construction like `val[name: string]: any` more dynamic than for example Java language.

Comment: I dont want to create new data class for each member type

Comment: If you want to store any key in one data class, you should look on `Map`: 
ControlTagTypeImpl(type = "X", properties = mapOf("TAG_1" to "TAG_X"))

Comment: I couldn't understand this: ControlTagTypeImpl(type = "X", properties = mapOf("TAG_1" to "TAG_X"))

Comment: interface ControlTagType {
  val type: String?
  val properties: Map<String, Any>
}

data class ControlTagTypeImpl(
    override val type: String?,
    override val properties: Map<String, Any>
) : ControlTagType